# Can I run F# agents on multiple machines?

Tags: .net, f#, mapreduce

Is it possible to run F# agents on multiple machines as cluster?

Comment: There is no such native feature. You could look into M-Brace (F# cloud computing, using Azure) or some any generic .NET framework.

Comment: Running is no problem, making them communicate is a problem.. It is just not as straightforward as in Erlang, but I believe you can do it if you put some effort into it. I never have.

Comment: Thank you, F# mapreduce frameworks if any? to run on multiple machines, instead of agent we can use mappers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible to run agents in a map-reduce algorithm on many machines, but there's nothing built into F# that does it automatically.

You'll need to implement a map-reduce algorithm, have the agents running on the cluster, likely as windows services, and then communicate between the source and the agents, likely via WCF.